# Weather Feeds - Need monthly average temperature by city

Tags: weather-api

Have a requirement to get monthly average temperature from any weather API by city. On going through posts, I have seen wunderground and other stuff but daily average is as far as I got. Getting monthly averages using this would push me to a premium service because of the number of calls I would end up making.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.usclimatedata.com/ has this data, but I haven't seen that they have an API for it.  I've contacted them and will report back when I hear from them on it.